# Cookie does not set using Golang

Tags: go, cookies

I have a REST API for login a user which sets a cookie on the browser for logged-in user and its working well.
The problem is when I want to call login API when user completed their registration from signup API, so that time every thing working well but cookie doesn't set to browser.

Here is login API:

```
var loginViaDjangoApiShim = http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        var t loginPost
        var oldCookieToken string

        decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
        _:= decoder.Decode(&t)
        expiration := time.Now().Add(365 * 24 * time.Hour)

        flagToReturn, cookie, _:= postToApiShim(t.Username, t.Password)
        if flagToReturn == "pass" {
            CookieToken = generateOldCookie(authIdFromUserName.ID)

            newCookieToSet := http.Cookie{Name: "ddagyeog", Value: CookieToken , Expires: expiration, Domain: COOKIE_DOMAIN, Path: "/", Secure: false, HttpOnly: true}
            http.SetCookie(w, &newCookieToSet)
        }
        returnValues := returnLoginFlag{Flag: flagToReturn, Cookie: ""}
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(returnValues)

    })
```

And here registration API:

```
var signUpStart = http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var t StartFlowPost

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    _:= decoder.Decode(&t)
        insertIntoUser := InsertMethod(t)
            flag, _ := loginOnCoppaAndNonCoppaUsersSignup(t.UserName, t.Password)

        log.Println(flag)
        json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(flag)

})
```

And below is `loginOnCoppaAndNonCoppaUsersSignup` which calls login API after signup user.

```
func loginOnCoppaAndNonCoppaUsersSignup(userName, password string) (flag returnSignUpFlagCoppa, err error) {
    var loginFlag returnLoginFlag
    var jsonStr = []byte(`{
    "username":"` + userName + `",
    "password":"` + password + `"
    }`)

    request, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", USER_ROOT_URL+"login", bytes.NewBuffer(jsonStr))
    request.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

    client := &http.Client{}
    response, _:= client.Do(request)

    decoder := json.NewDecoder(response.Body)
    if err = decoder.Decode(&loginFlag); err != nil {
        return flag, err
    }

    if loginFlag.Flag == "pass" {
        flag = returnSignUpFlagCoppa{Flag: "pass", Username: userName}
        log.Println(flag)
    } else {
        flag := returnSignUpFlagCoppa{Flag: "error"}
        log.Println(flag)
    }

    return flag, nil
}
```

Comment: Use a custom net/http.Client with a non-nil Jar. Get a jar from net/http/cookiejar.New.

Answer (score 2):

Here you can get cookie from login URL response like.

```
cookies := response.Cookies()
```

Then you have to set those cookies with `http.SetCookie()` again in signup API.Follow the below code.

```
for _, cookie := range response.Cookies() {
    http.SetCookie(w, cookie)
 }
```